# How does the mad scientist obtain a digital copy of the classified document?

Tags: plot-explanation, red-2

Late in [*RED 2*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1821694/) the "mad scientist" Dr. Edward Bailey claims that he himself published the classified document on the Internet using a phone that he stole from the asylum guard.

The classified document clearly originated on paper, so to publish the document using some random phone Dr. Bailey needed to have a digital copy of the document. Perhaps he could have used the phone camera to take a picture of the document if he had access to the it more or less at the time when the movie events take place, but that doesn't seem realistic - to do so he must have had the document with him, which wouldn't (presumably) be allowed in an asylum.

So how could he obtain a digital copy of the classified document?

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the question I saw the movie again.

The operation "nightshade" involved CIA, MI6 (British Secret Service) and Dr Edward Bailey, Marvin and Frank Moses names were dropped in the document so they they get looped in. Because of the Bad intentions (to set off the bomb in Kremlin) of the mad scientist the MI6 decided to lock him up. But since even he (Dr Edward Bailey) was involved in the mission he knew how it ended, and wikileaks need not always have the exact orginal copy of the document just the happening of the incident the mad scientist in his own words enacted the same scene in words and posted (using the cell phone of the guard) about the mission online.

Comment: not sure how plausible your answer is, but +1 just for attempting. This question has been bugging me for some time now.

Comment: Like i said I watched the movie again, and trust me this is the only logical explanation i could conclude to, i think you might as well accept my answer as not many takers are out there

Comment: I watched this last night and I've come to the conclusion that he didn't post the original document, he just posted the details he knows with the intent to include Marvin and Moses. So this is the correct answer.